# Forcing Yii 2 to use prepared statements on ActiveRecord model save

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

To be more clear with my question, I know that there is  [yii\db\Command](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html%20yii%5Cdb%5CCommand) and [bindValue()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#bindValue()-detail) and  bindParam() methods, but I'm looking at possibility to have ActiveRecord do it by itself. I don't want to write all queries manually, but to use builtin functions.

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord{
      public static function tableName(){
          return 'user';
      }
      public function rules(){ ... }
}
...

$user= new User();
$user->firstName='John';
$user->lastName='Doe';
$user->save();
```

When I look at SQL that is being executed after calling $model->save() I see plain SQL statements like `[yii\db\Command::execute]`INSERT INTO `user` (`firstName`, `lastName`,...) VALUES ('John', 'Doe', ...)

The same applies to select statements:
[yii\db\Command::query] `SELECT * FROM`user`WHERE`id`=23`

I would expect that framework should create prepared statements and bind parameters.That would be mush faster.

Is there a way to force it to make prepared statements instead of plain SQL?

Comment: I appreciate your approach, but you should discuss this at github.com/yiisoft/yii2/ with all core Yii developer. Discussing at github.com increases chances that more person will listen to your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

For complex SQL statement that is to be executed multiple times, as stated in [the docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-command.html#prepare()-detail) this may improve performance. For SQLstatement with binding parameters, this method is invoked automatically.

Or, you can use [QueryBuilder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#prepare()-detail) to generate query.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know about these methods you have mentioned, but I'm looking at possibility to configure framework to use prepared statements out of box (see my edited post), and not to make explicit queries avery time.